# Regex is not matching negative integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a query for my `Payment` model. My `amount` column is an integer. I want to eliminate negative integers from my `amount` column. I just want to show payments with positive values.

```
Payment.where('amount NOT REGEXP ?', '^-\d+$')
```

and

```
Payment.where('amount NOT REGEXP ?', '^-\d*\.?\d+$'
```

both work in Rubular, but do not work in my Rails app. I tried matching in the console, and it does not work too:

```
amount.to_i =~ /^-\d*\.?\d+$/
```

I know that `>= 0` condition will work, but I wonder why it does not work with `REGEX`.

Comment: (1) `^` and `$` mean beginning/ending of *line*, not *string* in Ruby, you want `\A` and `\z` in Ruby. (2) regexes are for strings, not numbers. (3) Ruby regexes are not the same as your database's regexes, every environment has its own idea about how regexes work and what specific syntax is allowed. I'd guess you're using MySQL as your database. (4) Why are you bothering with decimal points when you're working with integers?

Comment: I think just `/^-/` is enough

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to remove negative integers, wouldn't something like this work equally well, while being more performant?

```
Payment.where('amount >= 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your regexp works in console.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> /^-\d*\.?\d+$/ =~ "-3"
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> $~
=> #<MatchData "-3">
irb(main):003:0> /^-\d*\.?\d+$/ =~ "-3.1415"
=> 0
irb(main):004:0> $~
=> #<MatchData "-3.1415">
irb(main):005:0> /^-\d*\.?\d+$/ =~ "128"
=> nil
irb(main):006:0>
```